# Multiple notifyObserver

Tags: java, sockets, model-view-controller, observer-pattern, observable

I'm working in a java project with Socket, MVC Pattern and Observer/Observable Pattern.
I have to do a double notify from a Controller to a view like follow:

```
    this.game.notifyObservers(new InfoMessageType(InfoMessageTypeEnum.SHOWINITIALMMESSAGE, this.game));
    this.game.notifyObservers(new InfoMessageType(InfoMessageTypeEnum.SHOWGAMEBOARD, this.game));
```

The problem is that the first notifyObservers works well, but the seconds look like it doesn't works. I tried to comment the first notifyObserver and the second now works fine.
it seems like is not possible to do a multiple notifyObserver.

For istance:
the first notifyObserver contain the String "Game Ready" 
the second notifyObserver contain the String "GameBoard Status: "

The Output is just: "Game Ready"

And if I comment the first notifyObserver the output is "GameBoard Status: "

I don't have any java runtime error, just don't print what I want.

How can I resolve it?

EDIT: before notifyObservers calls I add the observers like follow

```
for(ServerSocketView serverSocketView : serverSocketViews)
    this.game.addObserver(serverSocketView);
```

And i never remove the observers from the game and from the methods that i call

Comment: Would you add your `notifyObservers ` method? Is it the case that this method removes the game Observers?

Comment: before notifyObservers calls I add the observers like follow

**for(ServerSocketView serverSocketView : serverSocketViews)
    this.game.addObserver(serverSocketView);**
And i never remove the observers from the game and from the methods that i call
@MadMatts

Comment: Would you show us your `notifyObservers` anyway? This would help.